# Is it possible to use Guest Checkout with multishipping in Magento1.9.1? If yes then How

Tags: magento

Can you please suggest me if it is possible to use Guest Checkout while using  multiple shipping address in Magento1.9.1 ? If yes then how can I implement so.
Please help me with your valuable suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look like you want someone to share code or give you guideline.. Your question is not specific to  any problem which can be solved here.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to your question is 'no', Magento does not support this out of the box. For multishipping a customer is required. Long answer is of course 'yes', since anything is possible in an open source framework, but development would be required, as Ariful says more than could be written in a stack overflow response. Are you yourself a developer or are you looking for someone to build this?